# My network is blocking some sites but my wife's iPhone can access them

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, iphone, playstation

As the title says, I have been having this issue for a few days and it has been hurting my brain trying to solve it. I first noticed the issue when my PS5 was constantly failing to connect to PSN. I realised at the same time that I couldn't access playstation.com or store.playstation.com from my PC or phone. Connection always times out. The few rare times the sites loaded they did not load properly, the formatting was off and clearly some scripts did not load completely.

Similarly I could not access the PS app on my phone and later on I realised its not just playstation but also riotgames.com that is not working. I tried a phone hotspot from my 4G network and everything worked so I immediately thought my ISP is blocking the sites. After my ISP checked they confirmed they are not blocking anything.

After being so frustrated that nothing is working and changing router IP and DNS a few times I desparately took my wife's iPhone and tried to open the sites, and they worked right away. All of them. My phone is a Samsung and that did not work. Her iPhone is on the same network and no special settings set for her so I really want to know why her iPhone can access the sites and not a single other device can. Maybe I can replicate what is working and finally fix this issue before my hair goes grey.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the router? Or changing the DNS to something like `8.8.8.8` (Google) or `1.1.1.1` (Cloudflare)?

Comment: done that multiple time. Changed DNS to cloudflare, Google, Quad9, etc. Nothing works. Rebooted it and reset it dozens of times. What is really weird is that my wife's iPhone can access said sites with no issue but all other devices can't.

Comment: I assume the only devices that you can test are phones and your PS5?  Neither of those type of devices are within scope for Super User.

Comment: I am using a PC too. The PC is where I first noticed those sites don't work and assumed that is why signing in was failing on the PS5

Comment: Firmware is the latest version. I would have considered a new router but this one is not that old and everything was fine just a week ago.

Comment: @MostafaAbdulrazic - The only way to exclude the router is the problem is to perform a factor reset on the router and gateway itself. We can only with the problem that exist on the PC. We will not be able to help diagose the problems on your phone or the PS5 (directly).

Comment: I did factory reset on the router but that did not seem to help. I tried to do a traceroute and it seems to fail in the beginning which indicates most likely it is the router or the ISP is blocking it somehow, but not sure how to fix it still.

Answer (score 1):

Finally understood the issue. My ISP was and still is in fact blocking many websites for no reason. Perks of living in an oppressed country I suppose. The reason the iPhone is not getting blocked is because it is having a feature called iCloud Private Relay which acts a bit similair to a VPN and that is why it is not getting blocked.